# How to invalidate a super-interface method

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

First I want to clarify that I don't have any real business requirements for that, It's a **purely theoretical** question.

Assuming that we have these two Interfaces :

```
public interface SuperInterface {

     void doSuperStaff();

     void doComStaff();

}

public interface SubInterface extends SuperInterface {    

     // Something here to invalidate doSuperStaff()

}
```

Is there any way to **invalidate / disable** the `doSuperStaff()` for all classes that implement the `SubInterface`? So only the classes that directly implement `SuperInterface` can use that method and override it.

**NB:** I know that we can resolve that in a conceptual manner, but I want to know if there is a way to make that possible technically: using annotations for example ( like the `@Deprectaed`, which only instructs the compiler that the method is deprecated.)....

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: AFAIK no. That would also defeat the purpose of interface extension, IMHO. If you really need to split up functionalities, create more different interfaces and let each sub-interface only extend from those, which are relevant for your usecase. The given idea sounds like a code smell.

Comment: @DaDaDom thanks for your reply, but as I said I know that it's easy to resolve that conceptually, but it's a theoric question, so I want to know if there is some thing possible technicaly

Comment: That's why I think that the answer to the question is a simple "no, not possible" :-)

Comment: OK, so why not? why we don't have an annotation to do that? looking for your opinion if you have any idea :)

Comment: If a method is in a class and you declared a method with `final` modifier, any subclass can't override that method.

Comment: Why not? Because it isn't needed and is a code smell. Why enable something that is a bad practice, particularly when it is easy to design away the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** If it's purely theoritical and you are not stuck with a legacy design you can't change, then it's bad idea to try and remove Super interface methods on a sub-interface (or class). It's indicative the design is wrong (Dog -> Animal (useLegs, hasBody), Owl -> Animal (useLegs-??, hasBody). useLegs in this case doesn't belong in Animal.

But if you have legacy code you want to remove it from, and enforce it with Compile-time errors, this approach will work.

You can remove the method with Aspects. Create a pointcut that triggers when the method is called, add Around Advice which is triggered on that pointcut and throws an unsupported operation exception rather than proceed.

With AspectJ Spring syntax it looks something like this (Syntax details here -http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html)

```
 @Around("call(* SubInterface.doSuperStuff())")
 public Object removeMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("...");
 }
```

You can also use the native AspectJ language and it's Eclipse plugin  to have Eclipse (or your build) show a compile error on the call site if any code attempts to use it. I think that would look something like this (https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-decp.html)

```
 declare error : call(* SubInterface.doSuperStuff())
                : "Method doSuperStuff removed from SubInterface";
```

Comment: But this also will throw Runtime error, why did you said that it will result in Compile-time errors?

Comment: The answer does both - the Around advice throws a Runtime Error. The declare error syntax for AspectJ declares a compile time error (you just need to install the AspectJ plugin in Eclipse to turn it on there, and add the AspectJ compiler to your build system)..

Answer (score 2):

Limited, but the following helps a bit.

```
public interface SubInterface extends SuperInterface {    

      @Deprecated
      void doSuperStaff();
}
```

Or even

```
public interface SubInterface extends SuperInterface {    

      @Deprecated
      default void doSuperStaff() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("...");
      }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But it throws Runtime error. Yeah, we know, we cannot enforce it to fail at compile time, unless it is supported by compiler.

Answer (score 1):

As you said the answer is **NO**.

This is simple illustration, why this feature cannot be added.

> Firstly the meaning of Interface in Java is **Behavior**

Suppose if I create a new interface `AdavancedComparable<T>` which extends `java.lang.Comparable<T>` and if I deprecate the `public int compareTo(T o);` in my AdvancedComparable interface and add my own method like `advancedCompare(T o);`

```
public interface AdavancedComparable<T> extends Comparable<T> {    

 // invalidate/deprecate for compareTo method using requested feature somehow

      public int advancedCompare(T o);

}
```

Any method which is accepting *Comparable`<T>`* type parameter will also accept *AdvancedComparable`<T>`* type parameter, but when the method tries to call compareTo, it will **break** if the feature you asked is implemented.

Suppose if compiler updated to recognize this issues and made to throw compile time error, that's fine, but it also has to support the **legacy code.** *Remember the Generics case, many classes which altered to support generic type, supports Raw type too (Like List, Class etc). Just to support legacy code.* But in our case it is difficult to do so, I feel.

Comment: thx that's also a very good explanation, it's just that I can't mark too answers as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Can not you use super Abstract Class which would implement doSuperStuff() and other concrete class could extend it to override other method.

Comment: This is a conceptual solution, I am looking for technical solution. Thx any way :)

Comment: if you use jdk8, then use default method of interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can always cast a subtype to a supertype, and invoke methods in the supertype.

However, there is a way to prevent overriding --

```
public interface SuperInterface 

    Object doSuperStaff();  // return value doesn't matter, can be null


public interface SubInterface extends SuperInterface     

    default Foo doSuperStaff() { ... }
```

Here, `Foo` is a package-private type. Subclasses of `SubInterface` (in different packages) have no way to override this method, because they can't access `Foo`.

It's also possible to use a `private class Foo` there.